# 2d alien game/ errors in the code/ dont require pygame or anything advance im beginner

Tags: python

sooo im trying to make an 2d terminal alien shooting i dont know why but when i run this it dont print out

just in case you might dont know why i did`map1_1 = [" " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " "] 
    map1_2 = [" " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " "]
    map1 = map1_1 + map1_2` it is because in vim i dont know why but some error pop up saying the list is too long "line too long (109 > 79 characters) " if you use vim it would be awesome if you help me.

```
import random 
from time import sleep
from os import system
import keyboard

# row = 15
# col = 21
def printall(player_pos):
    current_pos = player_pos
```

so this is just all the maps

```
    map1_1 = [" " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " "] 
    map1_2 = [" " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " "]
    map1 = map1_1 + map1_2


    map2_1 = [" " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " "]
    map2_2 = [" " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " "]
    map2 = map2_1 + map2_2


    map3_1 = [" " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " "]
    map3_2 = [" " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " "]
    map3 = map3_1 + map3_2


    map4_1 = [" " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " "]
    map4_2 = [" " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " "]
    map4 = map4_1 + map4_2


    map5_1 = [" " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " "]
    map5_2 = [" " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " "]
    map5 = map5_1 + map5_2


    map6_1 = [" " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " "]
    map6_2 = [" " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " "]
    map6 = map6_1 + map6_2


    map7_1 = [" " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " "]
    map7_2 = [" " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " "]
    map7 = map7_1 + map7_2

    map8_1 = [" " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " "]
    map8_2 = [" " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " "]
    map8 = map8_1 + map8_2 

    map9_1 = [" " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " "]
    map9_2 = [" " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " "]
    map9 = map9_1 + map9_2

    map10_1 = [" " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " "]
    map10_2 = [" " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " "]
    map10 = map10_1 + map10_2

    map11_1 = [" " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " "]
    map11_2 = [" " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " "]
    map11 = map11_1 + map11_2

    map12_1 = [" " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " "]
    map12_2 = [" " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " "]
    map12 = map12_1 + map12_2

    map13_1 = [" " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " "]
    map13_2 = [" " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " "]
    map13 = map13_1 + map13_2

    map14_1 = [" " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " "]
    map14_2 = [" " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " "]
    map14 = map14_1 + map14_2

    map15_1 = [" " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " "]
    map15_2 = [" " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " "]
    map15 = map15_1 + map15_2

    map16_1 = [" " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " "]
    map16_2 = [" " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " "]
    map16 = map16_1 + map16_2

    map17_1 = [" " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " "]
    map17_2 = [" " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " "]
    map17 = map17_1 + map17_2

    map18_1 = [" " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " "]
    map18_2 = [" " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " "]
    map18 = map18_1 + map18_2

    map19_1 = [" " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " "]
    map19_2 = [" " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " "]
    map19 = map19_1 + map19_2

    map20_1 = [" " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " "]
    map20_2 = [" " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " "]
    map20 = map20_1 + map20_2
```

this is the list that contain the player

```
    player_1 = [" " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " "]
    player_2 = [" " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " "] 
    player = player_1 + player_2
    return player
```

this replace the player list

```
    if player_pos == 1:
        player[0] == "#"
    if player_pos == 2:
        player[1] == "#"
    if player_pos == 3:
        player[2] == "#"
    if player_pos == 4:
        player[3] == "#"
    if player_pos == 5:
        player[4] == "#"
    if player_pos == 6:
        player[5] == "#"
    if player_pos == 7:
        player[6] == "#"
    if player_pos == 8:
        player[7] == "#"
    if player_pos == 9:
        player[8] == "#"
    if player_pos == 10:
        player[9] == "#"
    if player_pos == 11:
        player[10] == "#"
    if player_pos == 12:
        player[11] == "#"
    if player_pos == 13:
        player[12] == "#"
    if player_pos == 14:
        player[13] == "#"
    if player_pos == 15:
        player[14] == "#"
```

just printing all the lists

```
    print(map1)
    print(map2)
    print(map3)
    print(map4)
    print(map5)
    print(map6)
    print(map7)
    print(map8)
    print(map9)
    print(map10)
    print(map11)
    print(map12)
    print(map13) 
    print(map14)
    print(map15)
    print(map16)
    print(map17)
    print(map18)
    print(map19)
    print(map20)
    print(player)
    return player    
    return current_pos
    return player_pos
```

this is the text at the beginning

```
def main():
    print("THIS IS AN ALIAN GAME")
    sleep(2) 
    system("Cls")
    print("YOUR OBJECTIVE IS TO ALUMATE ALL THE ALIAN WITH THE SPACE CRAFT")
    sleep(2)
    system("cls")
    while True:
        print("HOW MANY ALIAN DO YOU WANT *IT HAVE TO BE MORE THAN 5 LESS THAN 20")
        amo = input(">>> ")
        amo = int(amo)
        if amo < 5 and amo < 20:
            break
        else:
            print("RETRY *THE NUMBER HAVE TO BE MORE THAN 5")
            system("cls")
    system("cls")
    print("CONTROLL: A = LEFT D = RIGHT")
    sleep(5)
    system("cls")
    print("START")
    sleep(2)
    system("cls")
    while True: 
        # main code

        printall(7)
        sleep(1)
```

from here

```
            # if keyboard.is_pressed("a"):

                # printall(current_pos-1)
                # player = [" " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " "] 

            # if keyboard.is_pressed("l"):

                # printall(current_pos-1)
         # player = [" " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " "] 
         # main code
```

to here you dont really need to care

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Start with something simple. Just print one line.

Comment: You tried to seperate the values in your list with +-signs, but these need to be commas. When using the + signs you will just create a long empty string, which does indeed not show up when printing. Also, the IDE should never permit you from doing anything. Are you sure the plugin for PEP8 is not just active, giving you suggestions on how to format code? Furthermore I would suggest using PDB to walk through code instead of using print statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, there's a lot to unpack here.

Firstly, what do you *expect* your variables like `map8` etc. to look like? They're lists, because you've surrounded the values in `[` `]`, but they're lists of two values because adding strings together results in a new string with the contents concatenated. Trying this in the python REPL:

```
>>> map8_1 = [" " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " "]
>>> map8_2 = [" " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " " + " "]
>>> map8 = map8_1 + map8_2
>>> print(map8)
['       ', '        ']
```

Given that some of these variables you want to update individual elements of later, I suspect you want lists of single characters:

```
>>> map8_1 = [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "]
>>> map8_2 = [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "]
>>> map8 = map8_1 + map8_2
>>> print(map8)
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
```

Or, more succinctly:

```
>>> map8 = [" "] * 15
>>> print(map8)
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
```

Your code for updating the player:

```
if player_pos == 1:
    player[0] == "#"
if player_pos == 2:
    player[1] == "#"
... repeat lots
```

You're using `==` in the condition of the if, which is correct, but then it looks like you're trying to use it to assign values too, which isn't what you want. `x == y` doesn't change `x`, it just returns `True` or `False`, which in your case you're ignoring anyway. Use `=` to assign values.

This whole section would be better written as:

```
player[player_pos - 1] = "#"
```

But that also ignores the fact that you might want to set the old player position back to `" "`. Maybe it should be:

```
player = [" "] * 15
player[player_pos - 1] = "#"
```

At the end of your print all function, you have:

```
return player    
return current_pos
return player_pos
```

As soon as you hit the first of these, you'll exit the function and return that value. You can only return one thing from a function. That thing could be a tuple of multiple values, so:

```
return (player, current_pos, player_pos)
```

Would be *legal*. You would then have to unpack it in the caller, but it looks like you're ignoring returned values in the caller anyway?

Lastly, you're printing lists, which I don't think is what you actually want to do. I think what you want to do is turn those into a string a print that.

Instead of:

```
print(map8)
```

You might instead want:

```
print("".join(map8))
```

That's just what occurs to me from a brief look at your code. There might be other issues. You'll get a better response to your questions if you reduce your problem to something small and specific, and ask a separate question for each problem.

In terms of vim, complaining about line length isn't something vim does by itself - presumably you've installed some plugin that does style checking (79 characters is the length recommended by PEP-8). You'll need to look up how to configure your specific plugins. For example, I use ALE which hands off to (among other things) flake8 to style check my code, I change this setting using:

```
let g:ale_python_flake8_options = "--max-line-length=99"
```

Comment: oh my thanks soo much now i know why people use this lol. and so do i add the let g:ale_python_flake8_options = "--max-line-length=99" in the .vimrc file? thx in advance

Comment: If ALE is the vim plugin you're use, yes.